# Python: If error occurs anywhere, do specific line of code

Tags: error-handling, try-except

I have a script I'm trying to write to process a large amount of data. There are, of course, potential for errors. In the script I need to connect to databases. If the script encounters an error, the code never reaches the point where the connection to the database is terminated. I'd like to have something in my python code that will recognize an error occurs, not matter where, and if nothing else at least close those databases. Does something like this exist? I know I can use try/except, but that would only work if I know exactly where I could get the error? I'm basically looking for a catchall to close my databases in the event an error occurs in a location I didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 0):

To run certain cleanup code even if there is an error, use the `finally` block:

```
try:
   # do stuff, possible exception
except:
   # run this if exception
finally:
   # always run this, even if exception
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: finally seems like a nifty little thing. Thanks so much!